# How can I put masked date input in a dynamically created text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, maskedinput

I am using jquery date input plugin from [here](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

I call the function inside the html page like this

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#date").mask("99/99/9999");

});
```

It works fine in every fields where we just have to specify the id of the element.

I have a [table](http://jsfiddle.net/nKkhW/6/) which creates table rows of html elements dynamically, I want the date input plugin to apply date mask in the text box having mfd date.

Since the id keeps changing dynamically as the row length is being added one by one to the id to make the id unique.

How can i use the masked date input inside the dom table ?

Comment: Why don't you add a class that doesn't change and call it on that class?

Comment: tried that but its not working :(

Comment: @nikc.org please have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/nKkhW/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the work inside your `insSpec` function, where you have both the ID and the markup at your disposal.

Without using the ID:

```
$(f).find('input[name^="mfd_date"]').mask('99/99/9999');
```

Using the ID:

```
$(f).find('#mfd_date'+rl).mask('99/99/9999');
```

And since that cell really only has one input, you only need to look for the input

```
$(f).find('input').mask('99/99/9999');
```

Or you could emit an event after the new row has been created and attach the mask to the last row in the table always, or even pass the last row as data to the event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to use a permanent class. If you use ajax, maybe you need to use callback function to wait for a code loaded before you apply the mask. You can also use a bordering div or span tag around your input tag with the permanent id. If you have constant amount of input in form you can use

```
$('table input[type=text]').eq(n)
```

,where n in eq(n) is item number in the sequence of inputs